# Does react native include sourcemaps in the release bundle?

Tags: react-native, source-maps, metro-bundler

For security, I would like to remove sourcemaps if they are included in the release bundle of react native apps. I'm pretty sure they're not included but I can't seem to find a definitive answer about whether they are.

I can see in release mode the JS source is loaded from

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"]
```

There are multiple indications which suggest sourcemaps are not included but none of them really answer my question

- https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/profile-hermes#enabling-source-map
- https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/symbolication